# Google Drive API Browser - Default drive to all users

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I need to share to the employee tons of files of a specific Team Drive through our ERP. Since the files should be downloadable and I cannot redirect the users to the Drive page I need to download these files from the Drive by the API and show them to download on the ERP.

The point is that I cannot found a way to allow the Drive API through Browser connect to a single drive account with OAuth and allow every user on the App get the files on the view. All the ways I found request the current user an access to its own drive and it isn't what I want.

I found a way to do this with NodeJS API (without browser), but this will need too much data to transfer from the back to the front and it dont seems to much smart since (I believe) I can download directly from the Drive to the Client without need to pass by my server, but I can't found a way to do this.

What I really searching for is a way to allow a specific domain to aways access a specific user Google Drive with certains credentials and, knowing this, dont request to every user using the app authorization to its own drive.

Comment: You can do this with a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts). You can check out the support article on creating them [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en) and a run-down of domain-wide delegation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation). This is too borad of a question for Stackoverflow, but I sugguest you take a look at these and then come back with any code-specific questions with all the information of what you've tried.

Comment: Hey @RafaGuillermo really thank you, I know that my question isn't a stackoverflow style question and sorry for this, but I was lost on that problem. Anyway, thank you again.